# Transient vs. Atom

Tags: clojure

I'd like to learn about advantages/disadvantages of transients vs. atoms. What are the typical use cases?

In particular, my concern is to transform a collection that is returned from a MySQL database. There are up to 4 rows per entity. I'd like to resume it into one map key per entity and do some processing on the value(s).

Thank you in advance -

Answer (score 5):

Transients are intented to provide very locally mutable collections for performance reasons - if you don't need the performance, there is no reason to use them, since their API is designed to match the normal, immutable, clojure collections, except with more hassle.

Atoms provide potentially globally mutable state with explicit concurrency/multi-threaded characteristics.

You don't need either to basic data transformation or processing. Step 1: Make your program work with the standard immutable collections first. There is almost never a need for a step 2.

Comment: I have a MySql test database with 2 millions of rows where 6000 customers emit 4 kinds of events ending with true or false. The query returns 24000 rows. I want a map with the customer id as key and another map with the rest of details as value. Then I'll be able to map/reduce/filter neatly for billing.

The initial approach took some 90 seconds. Transients reduced it to 37. Atoms did in 20. Hardcoding events did it in 15.

15 seems OK, but I'm willing to learn more. I'm going to do the same in C# to compare.

Thank you -